# TypeScript - type definition for extended standard lib Math

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to use the javascript library

[seedrandom.js](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom)

in a TypeScript project yet can't figure out how to write a type definition for this lib which extends the standard javascript Math library with an additional method:

```
Math.seedrandom();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add to the `Math` interface

```
interface Math {
    seedrandom(seed?: string);
}

Math.seedrandom();
```