# How to fix: Property 'seedrandom' does not exist on type 'Math'

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'd trying to add [seedrandom](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom) to an angular project.  I have installed it and typescript definitions using npm. My package json has the relevant entries (below) so im confident it installed ok, and the relevant folders are in node-modules.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/seedrandom": "^2.4.28",
  "seedrandom": "^3.0.5"
}
```

Despite this, I persistently get the error: `"Property 'seedrandom' does not exist on type 'Math'."`  In fact, when I do `ng serve` the error throws in the console, but the web app works fine.  When I do `ng build` I get the error and the build fails.

I've tried defining an interface per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097411/typescript-type-definition-for-extended-standard-lib-math) but doesn't help.  And I've stared at the code for two days too, that didn't help either.

```
  getRandomNumber(n) {

    const randomNumber = new Math.seedrandom( '1234' );
    return Math.round( Math.round( randomNumber() * n) );

 }
```

---

UPDATE:
Following the answer from Myk I tried the following:

```
import { seedrandom } from 'seedrandom';

getRandomNumber(n) {
  const randomNumber = seedrandom( '1234' );
  return Mathround( Math.round( randomNumber() * n) );
}
```

only get error: `Module '"../blah/node_modules/@types/seedrandom"' has no exported member 'seedrandom'.`

Which is interesting because when I checked the @types/seedrandom/index.d.ts file is include the lines:

```
export = seedrandom;
export as namespace seedrandom;
```

How do I get seedrandom working in Angular??

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To implement the 3rd party library 'seedrandom' in an angular app.

Comment: Instead of `import { seedrandom }...`, try `const seedrandom = require('seedrandom')` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58193548/925478. Also, I'm not sure, but the typescript types module (version '2.4.28') seems to be for an older version of that package.

Comment: `ERROR in src/app/tools.service.ts(17,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.`

Comment: I dont know how to check the whether types are appropriate, but they were installed via `npm i @types/seedrandom`, so assume they are correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. I've been trying to get it to work in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbrvsu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) but it keeps importing the function as a string instead of the full function. I think I'm missing something that someone else could help out with.

Comment: actually your example works for me when i change the line `this.test = seedrandom('5')` to `this.test = seedrandom('5')()`.  But it still doesnt work in my project...On the import line I am still getting the no exported member error.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/seedrandom#cjs--nodejs-usage):

> Starting in version 3, when using via require('seedrandom'), the
>   global Math.seedrandom is no longer available.

So it seems that if you wish to use it in your Angular application, installed via `npm`, you should import the function directly and use the random number generator it returns:

```
const seedrandom = require('seedrandom');
const rng = seedrandom('<seed>');
```

Comment: Thanks, Ive updated the question following your answer

Answer (score 2):

`import * as seedrandom from "seedrandom";` followed by `console.log(seedrandom('hello.')());` seems to work for me.

[esModuleInterop](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) seems to have something to do with. I just copy pasted the first import suggested there and didn't bother reading any further, so I don't know any details.

Thanks to your preliminary "staring at the code for two days" I didn't have to do that myself and was able to find a solution that works for me in under 10 minutes. Thanks for doing the hard work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for posterity, I couldn't solve this and ended up using one of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript) as I dont need anything of super high quality